# input/output error that come back just fine. How to make sure it doesn't happen again?

Tags: linux, hard-disk

```
root@host [/backup/2013-08-15/accounts]# cd /home1
root@host [/home1]# ls
/bin/ls: reading directory .: Input/output error
root@host [/home1]#
```

Suddenly /home1 doesn't work. It used to work just fine. Yes I put one of my most demanding sites there. Then I started getting these errors. Is it possible that the disk can't handle the load?

My provider insist that it's user's error though

> Actually, I think this was a case of user error. Your hard drives are
>   all fine, and I've confirmed I am able to read and write files to all
>   mounted partitions (/home, /home1, /home2, /home3 and /home4). I did
>   need to run an fsck to fix several errors on your filesystem, and it
>   also appears you have a whole load of unresolved links leading all
>   over your system (fsck tried to clear some of these manually, all may
>   not have been fixed). This system appears to have been very poorly
>   maintained, however as of right now all disks and all filesystems are
>   accessible. I will put this system back online shortly and let you
>   know when I've confirmed it is back online.

So we have a system that's working just fine for now and then suddenly crash for no reason.

After doing some check my host provider says that NOTHING is wrong with the server. I got my server back and yea everything is working.

How can this happen?

So after all those checks and reboot, the server is running fine, including the drive. However, I am afraid of moving stuff to the server again. If it broke again it can cost me hundreds of dollars.

What should I do to make sure nothing else go wrong? How com input/output is in error but then it works again just fine now?

What kind of error is this that works now and then fail latter?

Call dmesg and got this:

I run dmesg and this is what I see:

EXT4-fs (sda1): warning: mounting fs with errors, running e2fsck is recommended
EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts:

Here is the stuff in context

```
EXT3-fs (sdd1): using internal journal
EXT3-fs (sdd1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode
EXT4-fs (sda1): warning: mounting fs with errors, running e2fsck is recommended
EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: 
EXT4-fs (sdb1): warning: maximal mount count reached, running e2fsck is recommended
EXT4-fs (sdb1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: 
EXT4-fs (sdc1): warning: maximal mount count reached, running e2fsck is recommended
EXT4-fs (sdc1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: 
Adding 4194296k swap on /dev/sdd2.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:4194296k SSD
kjournald starting.  Commit interval 5 seconds
EXT3-fs (loop0): warning: maximal mount count reached, running e2fsck is recommended
EXT3-fs (loop0): using internal journal
EXT3-fs (loop0): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 3):

Your hard drive is most likely failing. Take a look at the `dmesg` log of your server to see if there are any additional errors in there.

On occasion this error can be attributed to a software mis-configuration while other times it may indicate a DIMM of RAM is either failing or faulty.